# Proving connectedness of a closed set

Tags: general-topology

I am solving problems in topology of a previous year paper of our Institute and I could not think of this problem. Please help. Our faculty is  unfortunately not 
interested in teaching. 
Question is:  $A$ is the closure in $C[0, 1]$  of the set $B = \{  f \in C^1([0, 1]) :   \rvert f(x) \rvert \le 1 \text{ and } \lvert f'(x) \rvert \le  1  \text{ for all } x \in[ 0,1] \}$.
Prove that the set $A$ is connected.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is defined as the closure of some set $A' = C([0,1],B)$, probably in the space $C([0,1], C^1[0,1])$ if I understood your question correctly. To show that $A$ is connected, it is enough to show that $A'$ is connected, because [the closure of a connected set is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678032/the-closure-of-a-connected-set-in-a-topological-space-is-connected).

The easiest way to show that $A'$ is connected is probably to show that $A'$ is convex: For any $F, G \in A'$, and any $t \in [0,1]$, the map $x \mapsto (1-t)F(x)+tG(x)$ is also in $A'$. Why? Because $B$ is a convex subset of the topological vector space $C^1([0,1])$. I'll leave proving the convexity of $B$ as exercise to you.

Comment: @ Magma are path connectedness and convexity same, just two different terminology?

Comment: Path connected means any two points are connected by a path. Convex means any two points are connected by a *straight line*. Convexity is a much stronger property.

Comment: @ Magma thank you very much