# Prove that the closure of a connected set is connected (Using the fact that continuous image of connected set is connected)

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I noticed that most proofs given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678032/the-closure-of-a-connected-set-in-a-topological-space-is-connected) are from first principle.

However, I am wondering if we can construct an alternative proof, by the following fact:

> Theorem:
> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and let $f: X \to Y$ be continuous. If $X$ is connected, then $f(X)$ is connected.

(i.e. the continuous image of a connected set is connected.)

For a topological space $(X, \tau)$ and $E, Cl(E) \in X$ with subspace topology $(E, \tau_E)$ and $(Cl(E), \tau_{Cl(E)})$

If we can find a surjective and continuous map, $f: E \twoheadrightarrow Cl(E)$ (i.e. the image, $f(E)$ is precisely $Cl(E)$), this completes the proof by the above theorem.

However I can't think of a way to **construct such $f$**.

If we restrict $X$ to be a complete metric space $(X, d)$ with $(E, d)$ being a subspace, the completion of $(E, d)$ is precisely $(Cl(E), d)$.

We know that the completion map is an isometry which is continuous, but I am not sure about the case for $X$ being a general topological space.

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I shall emphasise that my main question is about how to construct such surjective and continuous $f$ from a set to its closure in general.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4350257/977780)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The closure of a connected set in a topological space is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678032/the-closure-of-a-connected-set-in-a-topological-space-is-connected)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. But I also want to know how to construct a continuous and surjective map from a set to its closure in general. I'll edit my question shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $X$ with $|X|\ge 2$ and $p\in X$ and define

$$\tau_p=\{U\subset X: U=\emptyset \text{ or } p\in U\}$$

Now consider $E=\{p\}$, then $\textrm{cl}(E) =X$

It's easy to show that $\nexists f:E\to \textrm{cl}(E)$ continuous onto map.

Comment: For $E = \{p\}$, could you elaborate on why $cl(E) = X$ instead of $cl(E) = E = \{p\}$ please? I almost got it. For instance, I can understand the following example: if we take the 2-point space $X = \{p, 2\}$ with the discrete topology, then $\tau_p = {\emptyset, \{p\}, \{p, 2\}}$ (i.e. the Sierpinski topology), by definition, $cl(E)$ is the intersection of all $\tau-$ closed sets that contains $E$ (which are $\emptyset$ and $\{p, 2\}$), which indeed yields the whole space. However I can't quite see how to prove this result for a general $X$.